# ServerSocket.setSoTimeout() не выбрасывает exception на чтении у потока

Tags: java, сокет

Открываю серверный сокет. ставлю ему таймуат 5000 мс. На `accept()` - валится `SocketTimeoutException`, что ожидаемо, если нет подключения в течении указ. времени. Но когда принимаю клиентское соединение, на операциях чтения из потока висит мертво никаких исключений не кидает. Так и должно быть? Каким образом можно закрывать клиентские соединения по таймату?

Comment: Вы же можете вызывать `setSoTimeout` и на `Socket`, полученных от `accept`.

Comment: Так это будет таймаут на их чтение от меня, а мне нужно чтобы сервер по таймауту закрывал подключения клиентов